# Azure P2S VPN with Azure AD authentication for Mac

Tags: azure, vpn, openvpn, azure-vpn

is it possible to have P2S connection from Mac with azure AD aunthentication?

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about#authenticate-using-native-azure-active-directory-authentication) Say AD Auth supports only OpenVPN protocol and with only Azure VPN client on windows. Can we use any other vpn client to make use this?

If so help me to setup it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently, it's not possible to have a Mac client with Azure AD authentication. You could vote up [this feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/39075688-aad-authenticated-p2svpn-should-support-mac-os-x), Azure team will improve its product in the future.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this in 2023 or later, Microsoft's Azure VPN Client now supports AD authentication (now known as Microsoft Entra) on Mac OS 10.15 and later.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/openvpn-azure-ad-client-mac

Azure VPN Client can be downloaded from the Apple App Store here:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/azure-vpn-client/id1553936137?mt=12